# Button to toggle single list value in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

My form currently displays a list of entries from a C# API. I want to be able to edit two of the three fields for every line with a button click. The button just Yes/No and changes when clicked. In the background, it should change values.excludeMrbxfer from 0 to 1 (I made a custom pipe to make it say Yes for 1 and No for 0) or vice versa. This is currently how I am displaying my list with the button.

```
<tr *ngFor= 'let value of values' >
    <td class = "align-left"  >{{value.binId}}</td>
    <td > {{value.excludeMrbxfer | yesNo}}
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name='excludeMrbxfer' 
                        [(ngModel)] = "values.excludeMrbxfer" (click)='toggleChange(values)'>
                        {{value.excludeMrbxfer | yesNo}}</button>  
    </td>
</tr>
```

My issue is that whenever I click my button it changes the values for all the list items in the table. the desired functionality is to just change the state of one list item.

My second issue related to this matter is that in my `toggleChange()` method I have to explicitly call out which element in the json array I want to edit for it to work. The same issue as before arises in that I end up changing all the `values.ecludeMrbxfer` values when I just want to change one. Here is what is in my component for the `toggleChange()` method

```
toggleChange(values: any) {
  if (values[0].excludeMrbxfer === 1) {
    values[0].excludeMrbxfer = 0;
  } else if (values[0].excludeMrbxfer === 0) {
     values[0].excludeMrbxfer = 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: for the first issue, pass in `value` instead of `values` in `(click)=toggleChange(values)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your template you looping over the `values` array with `*ngFor="let value of values"`.  Therefore you can pass in each value to `(click)="toggleChange(value)"` instead of the whole array of `values`.

```
<td> 
    {{value.excludeMrbxfer | yesNo}}
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="excludeMrbxfer" 
            [(ngModel)] = "value.excludeMrbxfer" (click)="toggleChange(value)">
        {{value.excludeMrbxfer | yesNo}}
    </button>  
</td>
```

Now in your `toggleChange()` function you'll have just a single value.

```
toggleChange(value: any) {
  if (value.excludeMrbxfer === 1) {
    value.excludeMrbxfer = 0;
  } else if (value.excludeMrbxfer === 0) {
     value.excludeMrbxfer = 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: I used an index in the ngFor loop to get it to work but this is a better solution. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue by adding an index to the `*ngFor` method in the table row and passing the index to the `toggleChange()` method in my component.

```
<tr *ngFor= 'let value of values; let i = index' >
                    <td class = "align-left"  >{{value.binId}}</td>
                    <td >
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name='excludeMrbxfer' 
                        [(ngModel)] = "values.excludeMrbxfer" (click)='toggleChange(values,i)'>
                        {{value.excludeMrbxfer | yesNo}}</button>  
                    </td>`enter code here`
```